# Nondeterministic finite automaton understanding problem

Tags: computer-science, automata

It is probably a silly question but I have problem understanding it.
Let's say I have to design a nondeterministic finite automaton that accepts the language consisting of words containing a string of three binary zeros or three ones.
The example of that looks like that (q0 is beginning state; q5,q6 are ending states)
[image]

But I don't understand if in nondeterministic solution you have a choice to which state you want to go why it can't be just only 2 states ? in here for example for input 1011100 you would go:

1 stay in q0

0 stay in q0

1 stay in q0

1 stay in q0

1 go to q1

0 stay in q1

0 stay in q1

(q0 is beginning state, q1 is ending state)
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An NFA accepts a word $w$ if $w$ governs **at least one** path from the initial state to an acceptor state. Thus, your second automaton accepts every non-empty word in $\{0,1\}^*$: every such word can reach $q_1$ (though of course it needn’t).

Comment: So it means NFA can't give the "non accepted word" (input) possibility to reach accepted end state. Is that right?

Comment: @afgark: Right: if a word **can** reach an acceptor state, the NFA accepts it, even if it can also reach non-acceptor states. The words that the NFA does not accept are the ones that can reach **only** non-acceptor states.